# How to use the material components for Pass Without Trace

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

I am aware that many material components are either a joke (good or bad) or somehow related to how the spell works (IE: fleece for illusion is pulling the wool over someone). But for [Pass Without Trace](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/pass-without-trace#:%7E:text=A%20veil%20of%20shadows%20and,tracked%20except%20by%20magical%20means.) I cannot work out the connection to material components.

What is the link between the spell, and the *ashes from a burned leaf of mistletoe and sprig of spruce* used as the material components?

The only thing I can think of is that burning something creates smoke, which obfuscates vision, and spruce smells nice so covers scent. But I assume there is something I am missing as to why mistletoe and spruce rather than anything else smelly or burnt.

Note: I am not asking for designer reasons, but for links between the components and the spell.

Comment: *Detect thoughts* is helpful example of this phenomenon.

Comment: Unfortunately, component choice is never explained and this does end up being "did the designers say anything about why these components for this spell?"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is ultimately asking for a designer's explanation as to why they chose those spell components.

Comment: @NautArch I think the connection between fleece and the saying 'pulling the wool' is quite obvious within the community without needing the designers to spell it out, so this is more asking about community knowledge. I really don't care why they chose it, just what it represents.

Comment: And while it's 'obvious', it's also not confirmed. I don't want to see a bunch of guesses, no matter how probable they are.